# Table naming convention for Laravel Eloquent hasManyThrough relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, naming-conventions

The main entity `Subject` has multiple `Comment`'s, and the `Comment` has multiple `Rate`'s.

How should I name the migration tables?

I've googled that the naming for hasMany relation is `subjects` and `subject_comment`.

Should the `Rate` table be named `subject_comment_rate` or `subject_comments_rate` or `comment_rate`?

Comment: I would recommend to use polymorphic relationship for `Comment` if you have another model that comment-able for example `Post`. So the table names would be `posts`, `subjects`, `comments`, `commentables`, `comment_rates`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default laravel pivot tables follow the convetion of naming the table in alphabetical order with singular names so if you want to follow the convention you should name your tables like so:

- subjects
- comments
- comment_subject
- rates
- comment_rate

You can deviate from this convention but then you have to specify the name of the pivot table when setting up the relationship

Comment: And if I want to avoid an excessive normalization, should I just use `subjects`, `comments` and `rates`?

Comment: Yes, you can have a comments table with a subject_id column and a rates table with a comment_id column then the subject model can have many rates through the comments